# Gröbner bases method to solve system of polynomial equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, groebner-basis

I am new to the theory of solving systems of polynomial equations using Gröbner bases and I am confused about the terminology. I will appreciate any help to clarify my confusion.

Some sources are stating that in order to solve the system of polynomial equations one needs to compute Gröbner bases (multiple bases) with respect to degree reversed lexicographical ordering, then change the orderings of Gröbner bases (again multiple bases) to lexicographical ordering, and then  transform Gröbner bases to either triangular sets or rational univariate representations. Other sources talk about a Gröbner basis. We compute a Gröbner basis (single) w.r.t. to degree reversed lexicographical ordering, then change the ordering of a Gröbner basis (again single basis) to lexicographical ordering...

If I have a system of $m$ polynomials $f_1, \cdots, f_m \in \mathbb{F}_p[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and want to find roots of this system of polynomials using Gröbner bases theory, then I first generate an ideal $I = \langle f_1, \cdots, f_m \rangle$. Then for this ideal with respect to the term order do I need to compute a Gröbner basis or multiple Gröbner bases?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groebner bases are defined with respect to some ordering on the monomials of the ring. To compute a Groebner basis with respect to a fixed ordering (say, lexicographical), a computer algebra package such as Magma will first compute it with respect to an 'easier' basis, normally grevlex or weighted grevlex using some algorithm (e.g., Buchberger or Faugère) and then transform that into a Groebner basis with respect to your chosen basis (normally using something called a Groebner walk).

If you want to solve your polynomial equations then any Groebner basis will do. However, you might want to use several different ones. From practical experience using these things, the grevlex ordering might offer a short basis, but it will not be a basis for the radical of the ideal, just of the ideal itself. For solving the equations, you would like the radical of the ideal. This is possible, but *hard*. The poor man's version is to just remove all of the powers from the defining polynomials of the ideal. Now, switching to a different ordering yields a new set of defining polynomials, which might once again have powers. Remove these powers, then switch to another ordering, remove any powers you might find, and so on until your set of polynomials stabilizes with respect to all orderings you might want.

Since you aren't generating the genuine radical of the ideal, you might end up with possible solutions that aren't genuine, but this poor man's version of taking the radical is computationally a lot easier, in the sense that it's possible this year, and you might still get enough to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! It made things very clear for me. I was wondering if the size of the field will play a big role in the initial computation of the Gröbner basis for the ideal $I$ itself? My guess is that mathematical softwares such as Magma will have a hard time with a field of say size $2^{256}$.

Comment: @Efeçiğdem It does play a role, but much more important is the number of terms in each polynomial, degree of the polynomials, and number of polynomials. For example, if all the polynomials are linear, the algorithm is very fast. What sort of numbers are we talking about?

Comment: My polynomials are not too big. I have six polynomials in three variables with highest power of each polynomial being 13. Also, in each polynomial I have about 30-40 monomials.

Comment: @Efeçiğdem I'm not sure Groebner bases will help here. Unless you suspect that the radical of the ideal has a really nice form, and it's just your equations that are ugly, a Groebner basis for such an ideal may well have thousands of terms in each defining polynomial. To compare, I was working with cubics, and there you can get something. Degree 13 with 30-40 monomials? Possibly. Do you have an example set? I can just run it to check.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David! I don't have an example set I was just working with some polynomials in general form and they all roughly have this general form. So if I understood correctly Gröbner basis approach might be beneficial for smaller polynomials, say in two variables of degree max two even if the field is large?

Comment: @Efeçiğdem I have used Groebner bases for up to 60-70 polynomials, but the equations are quadratics and cubics. It can get stuck even with 20 variables. But higher degree makes things much worse than more variables.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I have a system of about 10 homogeneous degree 2 polynomials with integer coefficients. How many variables do you think I can do before getting stuck? About 100? I'm mostly looking for solutions over the integers but any solutions would be nice. I'd be happy to find even a single solution (other than the all $0$ solution). Groebner bases are the best method for solving a system of degree 2 homogeneous equations in many variables, right?

Comment: You can use Groebner bases but if the equations are homogeneous then you can only do linear algebra on the equations with the vector space with basis all monomials of a given degree.